# Get data from datagrid in a view to a label

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dgAutoFill" x="11" y="234" width="934" dataProvider="{rssHln.lastResult.rss.channel.item}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="title" headerText="Titel"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="description" headerText="Omschrijving"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="pubDate" headerText="Publicatiedatum"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="link" headerText="Link"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

I'm trying to get the title from the selecteditem from this datagrid (which is filled by a rss-feed) in a label. I've searched for ways, but I can't find how I should get this done.

This is the eventhandler I've added to the datagrid, and the function:

```
dgAutoFill.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK, showDetails);

public function showDetails(event:ListEvent):void {
            lblTitle.text = ?;
        }
```

Comment: The code you showed for your event handler just adds a listener, but does not show the actual event Handler (AKA showDetails).  What data are you trying to get displayed in the label?  Is it the currently selectedItem?  If so, what piece of data from that selectedItem?  The title?  Or something else?

Comment: Edited with more information/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to create an click event handler, like this:

```
protected function showDetails(event:ListEvent):void{
  myLabel.text = dgAutoFill.selectedItem.title;
}
```